# Extracting a string containing a wildcard from a larger string

Tags: java, regex

I have a chunk of HTML I need to pull a word from. The string `realClean` contains the HTML.

```
<div class="smallfont">
<small>

Originally Posted By: chingy51o

</small>
</div>
```

I need to pull `chingy51o` out of it. I've been having issues with this for a while, so I have widened my search to just pull out any line containing `Originally Posted By:` in hopes that once I'm able to isolate that, I can go in an extract the more specific data from it, but I can even get that line extracted.

```
            String authorString = "Originally Posted By: .*?";
            if (realClean.contains(authorString)) {
                    Log.d("AUTHORS!", authorString + "\n");
            }
```

but that's not returning any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Scanner` object and search each line.

```
String authorString = "Originally Posted By:";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(realClean);
try {
  while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.contains(authorString){
       Log.d("AUTHORS!", line.split(authorString)[1] + "\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When you mentioned a scanner I started slogging my way through the docs to see if I could figure it out, then came back and saw the example code. This alone didn't give me the output I needed, but it got me on the right path. I now have it extracting the author. Thanks again.

Comment: the string realClean contains about 20 of the "authorString"s. Is there a way to have it iterate over realClean to pull them all? I've tried http://pastebin.com/mC0vR9tV but it only returns the first value over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this:

```
        int start = realClean.indexOf("Originally Posted By: ") + 22;
        int end = realClean.indexOf(newline, start);
        String realAuthor = realClean.substring(start, end);
```

You could replace newline by anything that separates the author from the rest of the document (like a space)

Answer (score 0):

I would read up on Java [Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and in particular [capturing text in a group](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `realClean` is a String, you need to be aware that `String.contains()` takes a `CharSequence` as an argument, not a Regular Expression.  If you want to perform regular expression matching against a String, you need to use `String.matches()` or create a Regular Expression pattern and match the String against it manually.